# Inconveniente con datos en campo de tipo FLOAT - SQL Server - Laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-server, float

Estoy haciendo un sistema de reportes, uso SQL Server para gestionar los datos, además de que estoy usando Laravel para ello. Ya logré mostrar los datos almacenados en la base de datos, en la vista de mi sistema, pero un detalle que noté es que tengo un campo de tipo FLOAT llamado 'Avance'....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Input de mi formulario es de tipo 'Number', y tiene estas condiciones...

```
  <label>Avance:</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="avance" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" name="avance">
```

Cuando registro los datos, se almacena correctamente y asi se muestran en el SQL Server...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando se muestran en el reporte, se ven de esta manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITO:** Agrego la funcion de la consulta de registro.

```
public function insertar (Request $request){

        $actividad = new RegistrarActividad();

        $actividad -> avance = $request -> avance;

        $actividad -> save();


    }
```

Lo que quiero es que los datos se muestren en el reporte así como se ven en el SQL Server, y no con esos dígitos después del punto. Antes cuando usaba MYSQL se mostraban de la misma forma tanto en mi reporte como en el MYSQL, pero con SQL Server me sucede este inconveniente.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Listo, espero se entienda.

Comment: No. En mi caso es que cuando imprime los datos en el reporte, me muestra valores distintos a los que muestra en el SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

La primera opción es simple, cambia el tipo de dato de float a decimal(2,1), te ocupará un byte más por fila, pero tendrás la precisión deseada. (4 por float, 5 por decimal)

```
create table decimales (num float)
insert into decimales(num)
values
(0.5),
(0.6),
(0.3),
(0.6),
(0.9),
(1);
go    
alter table decimales
alter column num decimal(2,1);
```

La segunda opción es:

Si Sql te muestra los datos como 0.5 y 0.6.... es como los devuelve al solicitante.
Sin cambiar nada de tú código, puedes probar a engañar los tipos de datos, haber si soluciona tú problema. Traerte los datos convertidos a decimal(2,1)

```
declare @table table (num float)
insert into @table(num)
values
(0.5),
(0.6),
(0.3),
(0.6),
(0.9),
(1);

select cast(num as decimal(2,1)) as num 
from @table
```

Comment: Considera que aunque correctas las sentencias SQL, el OP esta trabajando con Laravel; dado lo cual también debe´rias considerar agregarlas escritas con Eloquent o el query builder